# How timeout and retries works together in Istio?

Tags: istio

Here is example of VirtualService, using both timeout and retries.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: sa-logic
spec:
  hosts:
    - sa-logic
  http:
  - route: 
    - destination: 
        host: sa-logic
        subset: v1
      weight: 50
    - destination: 
        host: sa-logic
        subset: v2
      weight: 50
    timeout: 8s
    retries:
      attempts: 3
      perTryTimeout: 3s # perTryTimeout (3s) is different from timeout above (8s)
```

How it works? The documentation does not provide clear answers to this question.
I have three guesses:

1. Timeout always 8s (timeout overrides perTryTimeout).
2. Timeout always 3s (perTryTimeout overrides timeout).
3. The initial call's timeout is 8s, retry's timeout is 3s (contradicts the documentation. The docs says perTryTimeout includes the initial call and any retries).
4. Timeout per try always 3s (including initial call), but the total timeout for all attempts is 8s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is correct:

> 4. Timeout per try always 3s (including initial call), but the total timeout for all attempts is 8s.

It basically means that:

- An attempt is marked as failed if it takes longer than 3 seconds.
- There are going to be a maximum of 3 attempts.
- The overall waiting time for a successful attempt will not be longer than 8 seconds.

`perTryTimeout` * `retries` should not exceed the global `timeout`. If it does, the retry attempts that fall outside the global timeout will be ignored.

Comment: What happens when only attempts and timeout are specified without perTryTimeout, will the perTryTimeout be calculated automatically? and will there be any delay between attempts?